# How to add IF condition to check the field value in the VF page email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, dynamic-visualforce

**I have tried to add If condition but getting error Error: Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Name'**

```
        <p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>
        <table border="0" >
            <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Course_Enrollment__r}">
            <tr>
                <th>CI</th>                  
                <td>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF((relatedTo.Course_Enrollment__r.Name = 'CI'), true, false)}">
                    {!cx.hed__Grade__c}
                </apex:outputpanel>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
            <tr>
                <th>DD</th>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>EL</th>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>PR</th>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to access `Name` field on `List` of sobjects.

`relatedTo.Course_Enrollment__r` means, that it is [relationship](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects) and that means, that it is an array of Sobjects

`<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Course_Enrollment__r}">` means that you are iterating sobjects, that are in `Course_Enrollment__r` relationship and name of its list member is `cx`. So change

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF((relatedTo.Course_Enrollment__r.Name = 'CI'), true, false)}">
```

to

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!cx.Name = 'CI'}">
```

besides `{!IF((condition), true, false)}` equals to `{!condition}`

Answer (score 1):

The error message means exactly what it says. `relatedTo.Course_Enrollment__r` is the `VisualforceArrayList` you're iterating over in the `apex:repeat`, and within that iteration `cx` represents the list member. Name is a property of the latter, so it should be `cx.name`.